# How to use array values in asynchronous function

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, iteration

I have an array, whose values I want to use as input to an asynchronous function. But when I iterate through my array and send them to the asynchronous function, all calls to the asynchronous function seems to be done by the last value in the array.

I thought that this kind of problems were solved by callbacks, but the function is a library that I'm using, which doesn't provide any callback.. What should I do to make the asynchronous function treat all individual array values??

```
var libraryName = new Library("#div");

$.post("myfile.php", {somedata}, function(data){
    console.log(data); //prints all correct values
    for(i in data){
        libraryName.asynchronousFunction({
            name: data[i].name // <--this value only becomes the last value in the data-array for all calls
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: can you show us the `asynchronousFunction` - body? put a console-log - call into the head of your asynchonousFunction to see, how many times it gets called

Comment: Your syntax is invalid. Do you call the asynchronous function with an object, or is there some callback function?

Comment: added one row, that initializes the library. No sry, the library is compressed..

Comment: The syntax you wrote is wrong. or you pass to `libraryName.asynchronousFunction` an object (therefore `name: data[i].name` is wrapped by '{}') or a function where inside you use `data[i].name`. The latter can explain the problem you have, that is a common closure misunderstanding.

Comment: Yes sry, that's what I did. Edited that now. What is the closure-solution then?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this because of closures:

```js
$.post("myfile.php", {somedata}, function(data){
    console.log(data); //prints all correct values
    for(i in data){
        (function(elem) {
            libraryName.asynchronousFunction(
                {name: elem.name}
            );
        })(data[i]);
    }
});
```